# Function to get custom post image URL

Tags: urls, images

I have to retrieve the URL from a custom post image, just the URL, like: `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/blablba.jpg`.

The code which I have to filter is this:

```
 <?php cp_get_image_url(); ?>
```

which returns this:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/816104.jpg" class="img-main" data-rel="colorbox" title="Chevrolet A10"><img src="http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/816104-200x149.jpg" title="6" alt="6" /></a>
```

I tried some functions using `wp_get_attachment_image_src` with no success.

Example:

```
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(  cp_get_image_url() ); echo $image[0]; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us what the cp_get_image_url() function does?
Is it from a plugin or theme?

Is the image uploaded to the Featured Image or a Custom Field?

---

Without knowing what that function is actually doing, the best I could come up with is this:

```
<?php
    $media = get_attached_media('image');

    foreach($media as $m) {

        $mee = wp_get_attachment_url($m->ID);

        echo $mee;

    }
?>
```

This will get all images attached to the Post. So you might end up with a couple of URLs

Comment: It´s from a theme. the image is uploaded to a custom field.

Comment: cp_get_image_url() insert a image in a custom post. see example: http://imgur.com/WQwWSP5

Comment: then you could find which custom field it uploads to, and check if it's the attachment ID or the URL then we could help you